# Postgres sum values from json only if pair of values exist

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

My json field looks something like this

```
{
"Ui": [
    {
        "element": "TG1",
        "mention": "in",
        "time": 123
    },
    {
        "element": "TG1",
        "mention": "out",
        "time": 125
    },        
    { "element": "TG2",
        "mention": "in",
        "time": 251
    },
    {
        "element": "TG2",
        "mention": "out",
        "time": 259
    },        
    { "element": "TG2",
        "mention": "in",
        "time": 251
    }
]
 }
```

I am trying to get the sum of difference of time per element which is as below

```
| element  |   Timespent   |
|  TG1     |     2         |
|  TG2     |     8         |
```

The problem is ideally for every "in" element there should be an "out" element which is clearly not the case in the above example. I want to only calculate the difference of this pair of values and ignore any value that doesn't have a corresponding out to a in. How can I do that?

Below is what I am using to get the time difference

```
select element, sum(time) as time_spent
from my_table
cross join lateral (
  select
    value->>'element' as element,
    case value->>'mention' when 'in' then -(value->>'time')::numeric else (value->>'time')::numeric end as time
  from json_array_elements(json_column->'Ui')) as elements
group by 1
order by 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not sure about you json_column attribute - you need to group by it in order to not mix values between rows, so I included it into window aggregations in CTE part. But you don't have it in your results, so I skipped it in final qry as well. In short - you can check if order number is even and equal to max order number and then just skip it:

```
select json_column
, e->>'element' element
, case when
 mod(lag(i) over (partition by json_column::text ,e->>'element' order by i),2) = 0
 and
 max(i) over (partition by json_column::text ,e->>'element') = i
then true else false end "skip"
, case when e->>'mention' = 'in' then -(e->>'time')::int else (e->>'time')::int end times
from my_table, json_array_elements(json_column->'Ui') with ordinality o(e,i)
)
select element, sum (times)
from logic
where not skip
group by element
;
 element | sum
---------+-----
 TG1     |   2
 TG2     |   8
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Im not quite sure how the query works here. What is "i" in this instance?

Comment: `with ordinality o(e,i)` i stands for index, e for element